# Over what scales can we begin to apply fluid dynamics to accurately model properties of the mantle?

Tags: geophysics, geodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Over what size temporal/spatial scales do geophysicists and geodynamicists begin to apply fluid dynamics to model the mantle rather than elastic/plastic deformation theory?

Comment: It depends upon your problem of interest. For example, if you are working to study 1) mantle convection it requires hundreds of years; 2) for studying subduction and earthquake process  you may require tens of years, 3) for matching the plate motion with the GPS reading, even few years are enough. 
For studies involving shorter duration the mantle movement may not be affecting the process hence can be neglected.

Comment: If you're still around, feel free to add this as an answer so I can close the question.